# Ext JS 4: Creating class with private variable array bug?

Tags: class, extjs4, extjs4.2

Let's say I have the following code (available at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/incutonez/A222D/2/)):

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
  Ext.define('TestBlah', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    counter: 0,
    counters: [],
    initComponent: function() {
      alert("counter: " + this.counter);    // should show 0
      alert("counters: " + this.counters);    // should show nothing
      this.counter++;
      this.counters.push(1);
      this.callParent();
    }
  });

  var one = Ext.create('TestBlah');
  //one.destroy();
  var two = Ext.create('TestBlah');
});
```

So all I'm doing is creating a simple class with 2 private variables: `counter` (an int) and `counters` (an array).  Now, when I create the class, I expect both `one` and `two` to not inherit from the other.  This is true only for `counter`.  When I create `two`, it has 0 for the counter and 1 for the counters array.  Even if I added in `one.destroy();` right before I created `two`, it still has a value for counters.  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug. When you declare a class, everything gets pushed on to the class prototype, meaning that they get shared across all instances. For "primitive" type values it doesn't make any difference, but for arrays/objects, those will be shared across all instances of your class. To modify this behaviour, set counters inside `initComponent`:

`this.counters = [];`

Comment: Why doesn't it matter for primitives?

Comment: Because they don't have reference behaviour.

Comment: Huh, ok.  That's interesting and makes sense.